# I have a web API for inserting data that works fine in Postman, but not in Android

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("RegisterUser")]
    public FetchRecord RegisterUser(RegisterM newobj)
    {
        FetchRecord objfetch = new FetchRecord();
        RegisterM objreg = new RegisterM();
        objreg.Email_ID = newobj.Email_ID;
        objreg.Name = newobj.Name;
        objreg.Password = newobj.Password;
        objreg.Phone = newobj.Phone;

        try
        {

            RegisterBAL Regball = new RegisterBAL();
            objfetch = Regball.RegisteruserBal(objreg);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            objfetch.ResponseCode = "EXC";
            objfetch.ResponseDescription = "Unable to process request.";
        }

        return objfetch;
    }
```

This is [my URL of webapi](http://mvcdemo.drugwrite.com/api/sample/RegisterUser) and the objects to pass are `{"Name":"","Phone":,"Password":"","Email_ID":""}`. It works in postman correctly but I am confused how to use in Android.

Comment: my andriod devloper says he is not able to insert data through this webapi

Comment: so the problem might be in his side not yours, If he sends the correct format of request then there is no problem in binding in your register model

Comment: is my webapi in correct? or do i need to add something

Comment: given that it works in postman then it is correct, the problem is in the android part, your dev might not be able to properly send a valid request